# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict' in odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to upgrade from odoo 12 to 13 by following the readme from :
https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-13.0

I have some custom addons in addition to odoo community addons. I followed the readme to make changes to the code. But while installing the addons I'm facing this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shani/fynarfin/odoo13/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 61, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/home/shani/fynarfin/odoo13/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shani/fynarfin/odoo13/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'odoodb13'
```

Full Stack Trace : https://pastebin.com/JLKKxAAK

Thanks for the help :)